# Prove that function defines a contraction

Tags: analysis

I'm reading [A First Course In Dynamics](http://books.google.ru/books?id=SrGeiW49TFwC&lpg=PP1&dq=hasselblatt%20katok%20torrent&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false), chapter about Lipschitz continuity.

There is an example I can't understand.

> The function $ f(x) = \sqrt x $ defines a contraction on $ [1, \infty) $. To prove this, we show that for $ x \geq 1 $ and $ t \geq 0 $ we have $ \sqrt {x + t}  \leq \sqrt x + t/2$.

Why is this enough to prove it?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x,y \in [1, \infty)$, with $x <y$. Let $t= y-x$. Then $y=x+t$.

So

$$|f(y)-f(x)|=\sqrt{x+t}-\sqrt{x} \leq \frac{t}{2}=\frac{y-x}{2}$$

**Added**

By rationalization we get:

$$\sqrt{x+t}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{x+t-x}{\sqrt{x+t}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{t}{\sqrt{x+t}+\sqrt{x}}\leq \frac{t}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for fast answer! I still wonder where that substitution comes from, but at least I can understand the proof now.

Comment: @lpaul7 Added something to explain the substitution. Of course using the rationalisation, you don;t even need to do the substitution....

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, using the fact that $\,\sqrt x\,$ is derivable in $\,[1,\infty)\,$ , for $\,x,y,\in [1,\infty)\,\,,\,x<y\,$ :

$$\exists\,c\in (x,y)\,\,\,s.t.\,\,\,\sqrt y-\sqrt x=\frac{y-x}{2\sqrt c}<\frac{y-x}{2}$$

since $\,\sqrt c>1\,$ .

Comment: Thank you, I like your approach more than one in the book.

Comment: Anytime. Perhaps the book has some educative purpose trying that approach, but as for simplicity and clearity the mean value theorem takes it easily.

Comment: Sorry, if I understand correctly, square root of x is greater or equal than 1, isn't it?

Comment: No, in fact we can take it actually greater than 1 as we can assume $\,x\geq 1\,$. Remember that $\,c\,$ is in *the open* interval $\,(x,y)\,$ and this makes $\,c\,$, and thus its root, greater than 1

Comment: I'm talking about *"since $ \sqrt x>1 $ ."* in your answer, but thanks for explanation!

Comment: Rats! That was a typo. Thanks, didn't see it before. It should be, of course, $\,\sqrt c>1\,$

Comment: Makes much more sense now :)